# ASP.NET MVC add css class to actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

How do I add a css class to this actionlink? I have read you do it something like `new { class = button }` but I'm not sure where to put it within my actionlink:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View Performances", "Details", "Productions", 
                    new { name = item.show , year = item.year }, null) %>
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

you can try

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View Performances", "Details", "Productions", 
        new { name = item.show , year = item.year }, 
        new {@class = "button"}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

If you do not want to pass in a variable you can do the following:

Html.ActionLink("View Performances", "Details", "Productions", 
        null, new {@class = "button"})

if you just want to add the class. Also, the "Productions" part of this element is not required.