# How do I add a class to an @Html.ActionLink?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two `@Html.ActionLink's` that I want to make look like buttons. I'm able to make this happen with `CSS` but only if I use the #ID of the actionlink to apply the `CSS`.  I want to assign a class to the action links but when I do using the code below I get an error saying I have a missing "}".

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Print PO", "PoReport", new { id = 51970}, 
                 new { id = "PoPrint"} , new { class = "PoClass"})
```

Here is the Style I am applying:

```
<style>
 #PoPrint 
{
 border: 4px outset;
 padding: 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:lightskyblue;
}
</style>
```

This works and I suppose I could just add the other #ID to tthe style but would like to apply the style to the Class.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608622/asp-net-mvc-add-css-class-to-actionlink
AND
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444495/how-do-i-apply-a-css-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @FaceOfJock, I looked at both of those posts and tried applying the solutions but was not successful.

Comment: if all proposed solution haven't work,you can use javascript as solution,you select your element by id and then add your class

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have to use the `@` character, since class is a keyword in C#. Here's a link to the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.108).aspx

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", 
         new { controller = "MyController", id = 1 }, 
         new { @class = "my-class" })
```

Comment: what if i want a class and an id? because the id in your answer is probably a parameter right?

Comment: okay i allready found the answer: `new { @class = "my-class", id=4 }`

Comment: This worked for me, but I hate having to do this. It's so much more work than just using good ole `<a href='foo.html'>click</a>`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that class is a reserved word in C#.  You can specify that you want to use the name 'class' as your attribute name by escaping it with the @ symbol like so:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Print PO", "PoReport", new { id = 51970}, new { id = "PoPrint", @class = "PoClass"})
```

Comment: Isn't that one too many arguments to Html.ActionLink? Shouldn't the `@class` be combined with `id` in the previous object?

Comment: @chris.house, I had tried that solution (from the possible duplicate posts mentioned above)  but got this error:   CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @AlanFisher - try  `@Html.ActionLink("Print PO", "PoReport", new { id = 51970}, new { id = "PoPrint", @class = "PoClass"})`

Comment: As jmoerdyk pointed out, I believe your arguments are incorrect.  I'm not sure what you're trying to pass in the first and second anonymous types (id = 51970 and id = PoPrint).  If you're trying to set the id of your link to PoPrint then you should just have one anonymous at the end like this: new {id = "PoPrint", @class = "PoClass"}

Answer (score 4):

You have to indicate the action name, controller and url parameters (null in this example)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", 
"ActionName",
"ControllerName",
null,
new { @class = "your css class" }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this `new { @class = "PoClass"}`
You need the @ for keywords like class

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i use null

@Html.ActionLink("Add User", "Create",null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

> "Add User" is Button Text
>
> "Create"  is actionName
>
> null
>
> new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }   CSS used bootstrap class