# Add CSS class to ActionLInk

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, actionlink, html.actionlink

Hey working on a mvc project
I have this link

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Testers.Name, "Index", "Video", new { id = item.videoId }, null)
```

I want to add a css class to the action link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
 As pointed out in comment, I made correction.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Testers.Name, "Index", "Video", new { id = item.videoId}, new { @class = "your_css_class" })
```

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643457/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink)

Comment: That is adding a route value, not a class attribute (and it would not even compile because  it needs to be `@class`)