# How to use class in ActionLink in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

Here The upper line is in html while lower is in asp.net but I am not getting the output from lower line as the upper gives.

[image]

The output with upper line is first one and the output of lower line is second one.

[image]

Why I am not getting the desired output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643457/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to an @Html.ActionLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643457/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink)

Comment: use url.content for anchors

Comment: I tried both but in vain. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Basic Information", "Index", "EditProfile", new { }, new { @class = "active icon ion-ios-information-outline" })</li>
```